# Sparse recovery, Restricted Isometry Property for ILL-POSED problems

Tags: compressive-sensing, optimization, linear-algebra

if $\mathbf x$ is $N\times 1$ sparse vector, and $\mathbf A$ is an $M\times N$ matrix with $M<<N$, and we measure $\mathbf y=\mathbf{Ax}$, then compressed sensing theory tells us that we can exactly recover $\mathbf x$ from $\mathbf y$ under some conditions for  $\mathbf A$ like RIP.

But what if $\mathbf A$ is an $M\times N$ matrix with $M>>N$ or $M=N$. Now the equation is not under-determined. But the equation can not be solved directly because $\mathbf A$ is now ill-conditioned matrix. To approximate to solution we can apply regularization. Since $\mathbf x$ still sparse we apply $l_1$ reguarization scheme as $$ ||y-Ax||_2^2 + \lambda ||x||_1$$ and find a sparse solution for x where sparsity level is dependent on $\lambda$.

The questions are

1) Do we still need to consider RIP for $\mathbf A$? What effects the acuuracy of the solution of $l_1$ regularization scheme except $\lambda$?

2) Why do we need RIP in compressive sensing and does it have any relation with the values of $M$ and$N$?

3) If $x$ is not sparse does this regularization fail for sure? Or it can still be work like $l_2$ regularization scheme. Maybe better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of compression sensing is to sample a signal below Nyquist given that the signal is sparse in a certain transformation. So it only makes sense when  $M < N$. Othwersie if $M>N$ or $M=N$ then what you have is conventional sampling anyways. An important property of RIP matrices is that it is guaranteed to only change the length of any vector  "very little" as long as the vector  is at least $K$-sparse (has at most $K$ non-zero coefficients. By definition its is the following: $$(1-\delta_S)||x||_2^2 \le ||A x||_2^2 \le (1+\delta_S)||x||_2^2$$ where $x$ is the sparse vector and $\delta_s$ is an arbitrary constant close to zero. So yes, $M$ should be less than $N$ for compressive sensing to make sense and infact all the known matrices that follow RIP are known to exist when $M = O(K(log(N/K))$ strictly. Finding these matrices is not trivial and is a NP Hard problem.

So you do not need to consider RIP for **A** when $M>=N$, because we are now not talking in compressive sensing terms. The $l_2$ terms should now be the objective because convergence can be achieved in the $l_2$ convergence.

If $M>=N$ and $x$ is not sparse then the regularization could still work but $\lambda$ should be adjusted accordingly with apriori knowledge of $x$ not being sparse. Although I dont see any point of the $l_1$ being part of the objective.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain what does $M = O(K(log(N/K))$ mean?

Comment: That means of the order of $K(log(N/K))$. Meaning the dimension M of the RIP matrix is decided by this relation.

Comment: Is not $l_2$ norms already in objective? What is the difference between minimizing $l_1$ norm subject to $l_2$ norm smaller than 'e' and minimizing $l_2$ norm subject to $l_1$ norm smaller than 'e'?

Comment: The choice of objective function, should reflect the desired property of the signal. If you are sure, as your 3rd question, that the signal is not sparse, then placing a constraint on its cardinality ($l_1)$ norm will naturally not lead to the closest possible fit in the least squares sense. Which would be desired since we know the signal is not sparse, so better optimize it in the least squares sense.

Comment: Minimizing $l_1$ norm subject to a $l_2$ constraint is basically trying to find a sparse vector whose norm is bounded, this is somtimes reuired and makes sense, for example, maybe we would not want a sparse vector whose one index lies at a very large value, we might want to find the sparsest x within the unit sphere.

Comment: Minimizing $l_2$ norm subject to a $l_1$ constraint is basically trying to find the best possible least squares fit by still constraining the vector to be at most 'e' sparse. If that makes sense for a problem, then sure we should model it that way

Comment: So if we cannot guarantee RIP for $A$ but we know $x$ is sparse, can we say the best approach is minimizing $l_2$ norm subject to a $l_1$ constraint? Also is this approach equal to minimizing both term as in my question? If yes it seems identical to  minimizing $l_1$  norm subject to a $l_2$ constraint because it can be written as in the form the question.

Comment: you can do that, but would have to know what is the maximum sparsity of $x$, the  $l_2$ can be used as regularization (you can use other penalty functions as well), clearly if you take the constraint to the objective, both problems would seem the same, but here is when the parameter $\lambda$ will play a role, its weightage will decide what is the actual objective and what is being regularized/relaxed

Comment: Yes we should know maximum sparsity of $x$ priory now this is why I found good solution to my problem by trying different $\lambda$ I guess. But on the other hand in compressive sensing we should know the error  'e' in the least square term. So still I will have to try some values.

Comment: It actually comes out of a constraint naturally when you solve a real problem, lets say we are trying to estimate  a sinuosid (clearly it is sparse in fourier domain), but i  also know that there is some noise in the signal, ofcourse noise is not sparse, so the least square 'e' will be a consequence of how much noise power there is expected to be. When you would solve an actual problem, these constraints will come out of self questioning. Hope that answers your question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107053/discussion-between-johanson-and-dsp-guy-sam).